# Search a folder for files like "/*tmp*.log" in Python

Tags: python, linux, file, directory

As the title says, I'm using Linux, and the folder could contain more than one file, I want to get the one its name contain `*tmp*.log` (`*` means anything of course!). Just like what I do using Linux command line.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) module.

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('./[0-9].*')
['./1.gif', './2.txt']
>>> glob.glob('*.gif')
['1.gif', 'card.gif']
>>> glob.glob('?.gif')
['1.gif']
```

Answer (score 2):

The glob answer is easier, but for the sake of completeness:  You could also use os.listdir and a regular expression check:

```
import os
import re
dirEntries = os.listdir(path/to/dir)
for entry in dirEntries:
  if re.match(".*tmp.*\.log", entry):
    print entry
```

Comment: Good idea, this will be better for more complicated searches which need more than *.

Answer (score 0):

The code below expands on previous answers by showing a more complicated search case.

I had an application that was heavily controlled by a configuration file. In fact there were many versions of the configuration each with different tradeoffs. So one configuration set would result in a thorough work but would be very slow while another will be much faster but won’t be as thorough, etc. So the GUI would have a configuration combo box with options corresponding to different configurations. Since I felt that the set of configurations will be growing over the time, I did not want to hardcode the list of files and the corresponding options (and their order) in the application but instead resorted to a file naming convention that would convey all this information.

The naming convention that I used was as following. Files are located in directory $MY_APP_HOME/dat. File name begins with my_config_ followed by the combo index number, followed by the text for the combo item. For example: If the directory contained (among others) files my_config_11_fast_but_sloppy.txt, my_config_100_balanced.txt, my_config_3_thorough_but_slow.txt, my combo box would have options (in that order): Thorough But Slow, Fast But Sloppy, Balanced.

So at runtime I needed to

1. Find my configuration files in the directory
2. Extract a list of options from all the file names  to put in the combo box
3. Sort options according to the index
4. Be able to get file path from the selected option

MyConfiguration class below does all the work in just a few lines of code (significantly fewer that it took me to explain the purpose :-) and it can be used as following:

```
# populate my_config combobox
self.my_config = MyConfiguration()
self.gui.my_config.addItems(self.my_config.get_items())

# get selected file path
index = self.gui.my_config.currentIndex()
self.config_file = self.my_config.get_file_path_by_index(index);
```

Here is the MyConfiguration class:

```
import os, re

class MyConfiguration:
    def __init__(self):
        # determine directory that contains configuration files
        self.__config_dir = '';
        env_name = 'MY_APP_HOME'
        if env_name in os.environ:
            self.__config_dir = os.environ[env_name] + '/dat/';
        else:
            raise Exception(env_name + ' environment variable is not set.')
        # prepare regular expression
        regex = re.compile("^(?P<file_name>my_config_(?P<index>\d+?)_(?P<desc>.*?)[.]txt?)$",re.MULTILINE)
        # get the list of all files in the directory
        file_names = os.listdir(self.__config_dir)
        # find all files that are our parameters files and parse them into a list of tuples: (file name, index, item_text)
        self.__items = regex.findall("\n".join(file_names))
        # sort by index as an integer
        self.__items.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[1]))

    def get_items(self):
        items = []
        for item in self.__items:
            items.append( self.__format_item_text(item[2]))
        return items

    def get_file_path_by_index(self, index):
        return self.__config_dir + self.__items[index][0]

    def __format_item_text(self, text):
        return text.replace("_", " ").title();
```